# How to formally justify matrix manipulation in countable-state Markov chain

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain with transition probabilities $t_{i,i+1} = \binom{k+i}{k}^{-1}$ and $t_{i,0} = 1-t_{i,i+1}$, i.e. we have an absorbing chain with absorption probability approaching one as $i \rightarrow \infty$. I feel pretty confident you should be able to approximate this with an $N$ state Markov chain, construct its transition matrix $T_N$ and then simply let $N$ go to infinity. For example, the average time $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ to absorption for the countably infinite state Markov chain would hopefully be okay to write as

$$\mathbb{E}[\tau] = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \boldsymbol{\pi}_0^TT_N \textbf{1}$$

completely analogous to a finite state Markov chain. But I want to be certain all the qualifications for convergence are satisfied. I'm guessing it's not enough for the transient probabilities to go to zero, they need to do so at a brisk enough pace. So I'm wondering what the requirements are?

Comment: Well, $\tau$ is a random variable and you have corresponding random variables $\tau_N$ for the $N$ state Markov chain. It should be easy to see that $\tau_N$ converges to $\tau$ pointwise. So you need one of the standard convergence theorems like dominated convergence to interchange pointwise limit and expectation. It looks like monotone convergence should apply here, because you are essentially collapsing any trajectories that go beyond state $N-1$ to absorb at that time instead, and not changing anything else.

Comment: There is no absorbing chain here, is there?

Comment: Yes zero state is absorbing